# iis rewrites rules matching parameters

Tags: asp.net, .net, regex, redirect, iis

I'm trying to write a rules that match `fr/Catalogue/?cf=jupes` and redirect to `vetements-femme/jupes/`

I wrote the following rules :

```
  <rule name="PapJupesSansGenre">
    <match url="^fr\/Catalogue\/\?cf=jupes$"/>
    <action type="Redirect" url="vetements-femme/jupes/"/>
  </rule>
```

but it's not working. I guess the trouble is coming from the `?` because if I try `^fr\/Catalogue\/cf=jupes$` it's working fine with `fr/Catalogue/cf=jupes`.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

`url` doesn't include the querystring part, you should add a condition to match the url and the querystring.

The following rule should work :

```
<rule name="PapJupesSansGenre" >
  <match url="^/fr/Catalogue/$" />
  <conditions>
    <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="cf=jupes" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="vetements-femme/jupes/" appendQueryString="false"/>
</rule>
```

The `appendQueryString` attribute will indicate IIS not to `vetements-femme/jupes/?cf=jupes`